# pixel selection for PanZoomImage

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am new to WPF and am trying to write a clickable zoom-pan image control. I already have a zoom-pan image which seems to work:

```
<Border Name="border" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Canvas>
        <Image Name ="image"> 
               Source="{Binding Path=Source}"
               MouseLeftButtonDown="image_MouseLeftButtonDown"
               MouseLeftButtonUp="image_MouseLeftButtonUp"
               MouseMove="image_MouseMove"
               MouseWheel="image_MouseWheel">
        </Image>
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

For the mouse and wheel events I used this post: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168176/Zooming-and-panning-in-WPF-with-fixed-focus

I am writing the clickable control by inheriting from ZoomPanImage and adding an event for LeftMouseUp.

```
public class ClickableImage : PanZoomImage
{
    public event Action<Point> Click;

    //...
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
         // ... all sorts of checks to distinguish click from mouse move
        if (Click != null)
        {
           Click(ControlToImage(mouseUpCoordinates));
        }
    }

    protected Point ControlToImage(Point controlPixel)
    {
        //this is where i am stuck...       
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't seem to calculate the correct image coordinates given the control coordinates. I need to take into account that the image can be zoomed and panned and that the window itself can be resized.

I tried using the rendering transform. When I zoom and pan the image I update the transform. And when I try to convert control coordinates to image coordinates I use the inverse transform:

```
Point imagePixel = image.RenderTransform.Inverse.Transform(controlPixel);
```

But this didn't work. One of the problems is that the Transform starts as Identity while in fact the image is stretched uniformly to the control's size.

Thanks,
Dina

Comment: Make sure that you set [Image.Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch.aspx) property to `None` before applying a RenderTransform.

Comment: @Clemens, Yes, I did that. The problem with this solution is that initially the image is larger than the window. I want it to be resized according to the window size. So I tried adding a callback that will be called right after the source of the image is changed and will change the transform. But this didn't work because when the callback was called image.actualHeight and image.actualWidth were still 0...

Comment: When you set the Source property (i assume in code behind) you set it to some [ImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx)-derived class, e.g. BitmapSource. Get the image size from the ImageSource's Width and Height properties and set your RenderTransform accordingly. Anyway, you have to avoid automatic scaling if you want to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved it. As Clemens suggested, I set the image stretch mode to none.

```
<Image Name="image" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" Stretch="None" 
                   Source="{Binding Path=Source}"
                   MouseLeftButtonDown="image_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                   MouseLeftButtonUp="image_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                   MouseMove="image_MouseMove"
                   MouseWheel="image_MouseWheel"
                   Loaded="image_Loaded">
                    <Image.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Fit to window" Click="FitToWindow_MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Image.ContextMenu>
                </Image>
```

This means that when the image is loaded into the window, you can only see part of it - depending on the window size. This is bad, but what's important is that the transform is identity and you can now manually set it such that the image is fully shown in the window.

```
private void FitViewToWindow()
{
    if (Source == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Source not set");

    BitmapSource bitmapSource = Source as BitmapSource;
    if (bitmapSource == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported Image Source Type");

    if (border.ActualWidth <= 0 || border.ActualHeight <= 0)
       return;

    double scaleX = border.ActualWidth / bitmapSource.PixelWidth;
    double scaleY = border.ActualHeight / bitmapSource.PixelHeight;
    double scale = Math.Min(scaleX, scaleY);

    Matrix m = Matrix.Identity;
    m.ScaleAtPrepend(scale, scale, 0, 0);

    double centerX = (border.ActualWidth - bitmapSource.PixelWidth * scale) / 2;
    double centerY = (border.ActualHeight - bitmapSource.PixelHeight * scale) / 2;
    m.Translate(centerX, centerY);

    image.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(m);
}
```

This function should be called upon loading the image and upon changing the source of the image. As for resizing the window - as long as you keep track of the transform, you will be able to convert coordinate systems correctly. For example, here's what I do for window resize:

```
protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
{
    base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);

    //center the image in the new size

    if (sizeInfo.PreviousSize.Width <= 0 || sizeInfo.PreviousSize.Height <= 0)
        return;

    Matrix m = image.RenderTransform.Value;

    double offsetX = (sizeInfo.NewSize.Width - sizeInfo.PreviousSize.Width) / 2;
    double offsetY = (sizeInfo.NewSize.Height - sizeInfo.PreviousSize.Height) / 2;

    m.Translate(offsetX, offsetY);
    image.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(m);
}
```